# Concatenate the name of the product with "-v2" if the id is an odd number, SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to concatenate the name of the product with "-v2" if the id is an odd number

```
CREATE TABLE PRODUSE (
IdProdus int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
Denumire varchar(36) NOT NULL,
IdCateg int NOT NULL
)
GO

SELECT IdProdus, Denumire,IIF(IdProdus%2=1, concat(Denumire, '-v2'), 0)
from PRODUSE;
```

The error is like

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Cablu USB-USB,
> 0.5m-v2' to data type int.

'Cablu USB-USB, 0.5m' is the first name in the table.

Comment: Probably because in some cases your IIF returns a varchar and in other cases it returns 0

Comment: And what do you want if it's an even number? Looks like 0, which has another data type than varchar.

Answer (score 0):

Your inline IF is returning two *different* data types - it's not clear what your intentions are but either way you should not be returning `0`, try either a blank string or the unmodified column:

```
Iif(IdProdus % 2 = 1, concat(Denumire, '-v2'), Denumire)
```

Answer (score 0):

- number % 2, if it produces anything except 0 then it is an odd number
- concat function to join the `Denumire` to the string `-v2`

```
    select
    *,
    case when IdProdus % 2 = 1 then concat(Denumire, "-v2") else Denumire end as new_name
    from PRODUSE
```

if your SQL supports IFF() function then you can also use this:

```
    select
    *,
    IFF(IdProdus % 2 = 1, concat(Denumire, "-v2"), Denumire) as new_name
    from PRODUSE
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because if your IIF condition is not satisied, in that case you are returning 0. In that case you should return the column value.

Here is the example -

```
SELECT IdProdus, Denumire,IIF(IdProdus%2=1, concat(Denumire, '-v2'), Denumire)
from PRODUSE;
```